# Como acionar opções de share no angularjs com ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Boa noite

Tenho um app móvel, tenho visto em alguns apps que quando clico em partilhar que aparece as opções das apps instaladas como facebook no telefone para partilhar gostaria de saber como posso accionar essas opções para fazer partilha por exemplo nas redes sociais como facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o ngCordova, com o plugin [Social Sharing](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/)

Para isso é só instalar o ngCordova com o bower e adicione o plugin

```
bower install ngCordova
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

Adicionar o script no seu index.html

```
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

E adicionar a dependencia no seu app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
```

No controller use o serviço $cordovaSocialSharing. A documentação de como utilizar está no github do projeto: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Eu consigo usar esse plugin para compartilhar um arquivo que eu crio em app ionic?